# Using response key from api as middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a web app & keeping my web client and backend API completely separate. I want to use the token from `sign in api response` for every url in my web app route as an middleware authentication. So if I don't have response from `sign in api` I cannot access the url.

I have sign in api like this, using username & password as header. I'm using this api when login to my web app:

```
$client = new Client();
$credentials = base64_encode('username:password');
$response = $client->get('sign-in-url',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $credentials,
            ],
        ]);

...
return $response;
```

My question is how to protect every url on my web app using that token? If it is in web app I usually using middleware to check if user already logged in or not. But what I need to do if using api?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a middleware and put it's address inside `$middleware` array of your `App\Http\Kernel` class. It will be applied on every request (both web and api).